# hash method to verify integrity of dir vs dir.tar.gz

Tags: bash, ssh

I'm working on a python scrip that verify the integrity of some downloaded projects.
On my nas, I have all my compressed folder: folder1.tar.gz,   folder2.tar.gz,  …

On my Linux computer, the equivalent uncompressed  folder : folder1, folder2,  …

So, i want to compare the integrity of my files without any UnTar or download !

I think i can do it on the nas with something like (with md5sum):

```
sshpass -p 'pasword' ssh login@my.nas.ip tar -xvf /path/to/my/folder.tar.gz | md5sum | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

this give me a hash, but I don't know how to get an equivalent hash to compare with the normal folder on my computer. Maybe the way I am doing it is wrong.

I need one command for the nas, and one for the Linux computer, that output the same hash ( if the folders are the same, of course )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you did that, `tar xf` would actually extract the files. `md5sum` would only see the file listing, and not the file content.

---

However, if you have GNU tar on the server and the standard utility `paste`, you could create checksums this way:

**mksums**:

```
#!/bin/bash

data=/path/to/data.tar.gz
sums=/path/to/data.md5

paste \
    <(tar xzf "$data" --to-command=md5sum) \
    <(tar tzf "$data" | grep -v '/$') \
| sed 's/-\t//' > "$sums"
```

Run `mksums` above on the machine with the tar file.

Copy the sums file it creates to the computer with the folders and run:

```
cd /top/level/matching/tar/contents
md5sums -c "$sums"
```

- `paste` joins lines of files given as arguments
- `<( ...)` runs a command, making its output appear in a fifo
- `--to-command` is a GNU tar extension which allows running commands which will receive their data from stdin
- `grep` filters out directories from the tar listing
- `sed` removes the extraneous `-\t` so the checksum file can be understood by `md5sum`

The above assumes you don't have any very-oddly named files (for example, the names can't contain newlines)

Comment: that works grate ! but is it possible to go even further, and to return a single "global hash" for the whole file instead of a big data file. To check, not every single file, but the folder as one single object ?

Comment: I've made this single line and, i fell like it return a hash of the data file instead of the data file : `data=/path/to/data.tar.gz; paste     <(tar xzf "$data" --to-command=md5sum)     <(tar tzf "$data" | grep -v '/$') | sed 's/-\t//' | md5sum | awk '{print $1}'`      But now I don't know how to generate the equivalent hash with my uncompressed file to compare it.

Comment: does `folder.targz` contain filenames like `folder/dir/file` or `dir/file`?

Comment: they are complex folder and it depend. for some of them :  `folder-name.tar.gz` uncompressed gives `folder-name/dir/file` but over ones gives `different-name/dir/file`. In all case : one compressed folder **give one** folder, but this folder contain dozens of dir with subdir and files...

Comment: my method provides the exact list of filenames you need to check. Without it, do you have another way to generate the list?

Comment: Yeah, i agree, it work great for the "folder.tar.gz". but now i'm trying to generate the same list of filenames with md5 but with the "folder"

Comment: However you originally unpacked (or created) the tar, with my method you just `cd` to the same place and then do `md5sum -c sums_file`. The sums_file already contains exactly the list of files that needs to be checked.

Comment: I understand what your saying. But in my case, I want to make a single hash code for the `folder.tar.gz` and a single hash code for the  `folder` and then compares the codes. For multiples reasons in my case, creating a dedicated `data.md5` file and then use it, make things too complicated.

Comment: That's why I asked if you have a way to generate the list of individual files to check. If you do, the problem is trivial. If you don't, you just moved the "too complicated" somewhere else.

Comment: no I don't, there is no easy way of doing it ?

Comment: how do you create the tar? how do you create the original folder of files?

Comment: they are versions of software install, convert to tar and then moved to a nas. when the software is needed again, we download and untar it. I am creating a python interface for the user, to handle this download part and check the integrity of the download. I should avoid creating any files on the nas. hope there's information make my problem clearer.